# Working with references and new

Tags: java

What's the expected behaviour of executing this line of code?:

```
Foo f = someOtherObject.getFoo(); //We get a reference of a Foo object from another class
f = new Foo();
```

Would someOtherObject.getFoo() return the new object, or the old one?, and what if we change the second line of code with:

```
f = null;
```

Would someOtherObjct.getFoo() return null, or the old object?

Comment: That wasn't my doubt anyway. I just thought that setting f to a new object might as well set the object pointed by f to be a new object. When coming from C++ and working with "real" pointers (not like those aren't real ones but they can't be manipulated as such) this Java references sometimes get confusing to me. Of course I was just confused, I got it clear now.

Comment: Setting a pointer value in C/C++ wouldn't affect the memory pointed at by `f` either unless you explicitly copied bytes. If you have two strings in memory, point at the first one, then point at the second one, the first one doesn't disappear.

Comment: I know, but assuming the same behaviour would work in Java or anywhere else isn't the way to go, and as I wasn't able to test it myself that day, I asked here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign different values/objects to `f`, you simply let `f` point to different memory locations, the memory that `f` points to does not get changed.

```
Foo f = someOtherObject.getFoo();
```

`f` points to object returned by someOtherObject.getFoo() **(some memory location on the heap)**

```
f = new Foo();
```

`f` points to a new object **(another memory location on the heap)**

**Would someOtherObject.getFoo() return the new object?**

Nope... because we did not change `someOtherObject`

```
f = null;
```

**Would someOtherObject.getFoo() return the null?**

Nope... because we did not change `someOtherObject`

Answer (score 5):

You can think of `f` as containing a value that points to some object in memory. When you reassign `f` with `f = something`, it just changes the location in memory to which `f` is pointing.

But that does not affect the object `f` was pointing to originally.

So in both cases, `getFoo()` will return the old object even if your reassign `f` (assuming your `getFoo` method does not change anything and is a simple getter of course).

Comment: The p______ word is not allowed in Java.

Comment: @CodeEnthusiastic Of course it is allowed. It is even used in the language specification.

Comment: [JLS 4.3.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1): *The reference values (often just references) are pointers to these objects, and a special null reference, which refers to no object.*

Comment: You posted first, so I put this here. I don't know if OP knows, though, that when there are no "pointers" to an object, as when `f` has its value reassigned, that first object is no longer interesting or useful and will be garbage collected before long. Now, there could be other code, not shown, holding the "pointer" to the object originally stored as the `foo` for `someOtherObject`. But we don't know about that.

Comment: @CodeEnthusiastic The important distinction is that strictly speaking, f is not a pointer, its value is. If that makes sense. I have reworded to be more specific.

Comment: @LeeMeador True, but the act of reassigning a reference (in and of itself) isn't what makes an object eligible for garbage collection. As long as we're being nit-picky, we'll have to be complete :)

Comment: @DaveNewton True. You can think of it as if you have to reassign all references. That, however, ignores that you could have a reference to it in another object that has itself gotten dereferenced. And that other object could be in a 3rd object ... Then it gets all complicated and won't fit into an SO comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
Foo f = someOtherObject.getFoo(); //Assign f to value returned by getFoo()
f = new Foo();                    //Reassign f to newly constructed Foo object
f = null;                         //Reassign f to null
```

In either case the `getFoo()` method doesn't care what you assigned to `f`.

Answer (score 0):

`f = null` does not affect the object returned by `getFoo()` in anyway.
or `f = new foo()` for that matter.

In both the cases, We are just changing the reference which f is holding.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases the value that `someOtherObject.getFoo()` returns is not affected. By reassigning `f` you reassign `f` itself, not the reference that `f` previously held.

Answer (score 0):

f is just a pointer to an object, so changing where it points to (f = something else) does not change the object it was previously pointing to.

Example:
(f being the kind of pointer you have)

```
f = existingobject;
f = otherobject;
```

All this means is that f first points to `existingobject`. When the next line is executed, f no longer points to `existingobject` but now points to `otherobject`. `existingobject` is entirely unaffected.